# Typescript - Further Exploration into "require" and paths

Tags: requirejs, typescript, ravendb

I had resigned myself to the fact that every `require` statement in `Typescript` had to be relative to the file you were typing in, but I recently discovered an application that does this differently and it confuses me. I was hoping someone with enough skill could explain how this is working to me.

The application in question is the new `Raven DB HTML5 Studio`, which uses typescript, you can find the whole application here:

#### [RavenDB HTML5 Studio](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/tree/master/Raven.Studio.Html5)

When browsing its source code, I came across something interesting... if you go and look at many of the files; In specific the one I am looking at... `app/viewmodels/deleteItems.ts`, it has a reference at the top that reads..

`import document = require("models/document");`

but `models/document` isn't a path relative to `deleteItems.ts`, but this **works**. Can someone explain how this is happening? I'm linking you RIGHT to the exact files I'm talking about. This kind of behavior is littered all over this application.

### [`app/viewmodels/deleteItem.ts`](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Studio.Html5/App/viewmodels/deleteItems.ts)

### [`app/models/document.ts`](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Studio.Html5/App/models/document.ts)

This is exactly the kind of behavior I really wanted to try and emulate in my own code, since trying to keep all of the paths relative to the file I'm working in is a headache, but this program seems to be completely free of that requirement.

This doesn't necessarily involve `RavenDB`, but I am tagging it anyway, because perhaps someone who has read over the Raven repository will understand it and be able to answer.

## Update

I am trying to mimic this behavior in my own code, and not finding any success. I am sorry if I seem outright stupid, but this is all really confusing me. Here is what my structure looks like; My repository is private, so I cannot really just link to it.

- app_content

  - scripts

    - home

      - controls
      - models
      - editors
      - utils

        - UserControls.ts
        - UserMapping.ts
        - UserElements.ts
      - ui
    - lib

      - jquery

        - jquery.js
        - jquery.validate.js
        - jquery.ui.js
      - kendo

        - kendo.all.js
        - kendo.aspnetmvc.js
      - // other libraries

Alright, that's a general feel for my folder layout. All `typescript` files are under the `/home` folder so that I can prevent `github` from saving their compiled javascript and locking that.

So then, in the file **UserControls.ts**, it looks like this right now...

```
import userElements = require('./UserElements');
import userMapping = require('./UserMapping');

export class UserControls {
   // code
}
```

No matter what combinations I have tried, this is the **only** format/syntax that doesn't throw errors in Visual Studio. But from what I see in the RavenDB project, I should very much be able to declare it like ...

```
import userElements = require('utils/UserElements');
import userMapping = require('utils/UserMapping');

export class UserControls {
   // some code
}
```

Comment: app/ is the root folder. When you do something such as require("models/document") it actually looks like app/models/document. This means all paths in your require statements are relative to app.

Comment: How is `app` the root folder? I'm unclear as to how this was declared or determined. Is this a value that is set somewhere?

Comment: I could understand it if it were `require("app/models/document")`, but it isn't... what specifically allows it to avoid the `app` part? I've tried doing this in my own program and it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question to show some more specifics that are confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No matter what combinations I have tried, this is the only format/syntax that doesn't throw errors in Visual Studio. But from what I see in the RavenDB project, I should very much be able to declare it like ...

That is because they are using a drandalJS configuration to tell it how to resolve the file path. (see https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/New3/Raven.Studio.Html5/App/main.js)

There isn't a similar configuration (`basePath`) for TypeScript at the moment. Your best option is to use relative paths as you've already noticed.

PS: an old but still relevant video that shows you how requirejs config works and relevance when using TypeScript https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AGQpv0MKsA&hd=1

Comment: Well, I could understand that if it were just the run time behavior, but I'm actually referring to the way Visual Studio interprets it. The fact that DurandalJS is included in the project changes the way Visual Studio parses it in design time?

Comment: That video is REALLY helpful, by the way. I'm going to try some of it and get back to you. This might be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, I say that, but now that I try it - it doesn't work. His use of the keyword `module` isn't working right, I think this video only applies to a much older version of typescript.

Comment: Use require instead of module

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript compiler's module resolution algorithm is essentially undocumented, unfortunately. It tries to "split the difference" between AMD and CommonJS's module resolution rules, so it's somewhat hard to reason about.

What you're seeing here is an attempt to mimic CommonJS's "walk up the tree" resolution rule. When in the path `C:\a\b\c\d` resolving `x`, first `C:\a\b\c\d\x` is tried, then `C:\a\b\c\x`, then `C:\a\b\x`, and so on until it hits the root folder and gives up.

Comment: I am afraid I do not really understand what you're saying. I've tried to mimic this all myself, and it doesn't work. In my program, the directory structure is `app_content/scripts/home/utils/UserControls.ts`, and there are two other files in that same directory. Trying to give them any path other than `require('./UserElements');` fails.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question to show some more specifics that are confusing me.